# Not getting alert on success in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my AJAX code. It's working fine and sends data to my database. However I don't get any `alert()` on success.

Can you tell me why?

```
$(function() {    
    $('#placeBid').on('submit', function(e) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(e);
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url: $("#placeBid").attr("action"),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == true)
                    alert('working');
                else 
                    alert('not working');            
            },
            error: function(data) {}
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the request in the network console to see the returned HTTP status code and response text? If you're seeing no alerts then it implies the request is failing and going in to the empty `error` handler.

Comment: How to check it ? I'm not seeing any errors in console

Comment: add an alert to `error` callback.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting then alert box

Comment: So like @Rory say request is failing... check browser console for details.

Comment: You can put the `$.ajaxSetup()` outside of `submit` event. and you don't need this `dataType: 'json',`, either remove it or change to `dataType: 'text',`

Comment: @Jai Thanks. It works when I used 'text'. Can u tell me why it's not working with json ?

Comment: @hulkatron `dataType:'json'` expects a json value like `[{key:value}]` and in your case you are checking with a string `true`. or i would say the respective url doesn't provide/produce a json response

Comment: Make sure you are returning a Json response

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `dataType: 'json'` option will fix the issue because the callback will wait for `data` to be `json` when you're returning I guess `string` because you're trying to make a condition `data == true` (by the way it will be never achieved because `data` returned could not be boolean).

So just remove the option and `dataType` will make by default Intelligent Guess for `(xml, json, script, or html)` :

```
$.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url: $("#placeBid").attr("action"),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == 'true')
        alert('working');
      else 
        alert('not working');            
    },
    error: function(data) {}
})
```

Hopet this helps.